# SSRS 2008 Multiple X-Axis Categories - Remove Brackets

Tags: reporting-services, categories, brackets

I am trying to add multiple X-axis categories to an SSRS 2008 line chart, but by default it is adding these brackets to each additional category.  Is there a way to remove these brackets?  I am trying to display about 50 data points and it the brackets are causing the data in the categories to be cut off/squished/un-readable.  Or if there is a better way of displaying multiple x-axis data.  Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Brackets in question:
http://i44.photobucket.com/albums/f39/sethmo38/SSRSLineChart3_zps348f76b8.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just click on the axis X or Y till you see a selected block outline and then click 'delete' on your keyboard and it is removed.  If you want to perform operations outside the norm but keep some of the options click properties instead.

The default is pane is Axis Options and you can change 'Category' to 'Scalar' if you want numbers.  You set expressions instead of the auto here if you want.  If you don't want that but want a custom labeling go to the pane 'Labels' instead.  You can hide the labels all together or choose an expression to determine when they are hidden.  You may wish to mess with the major and minor tick marks as well.  When you want to highly customize an axis you may wish to mess with hiding some of the major marks and potentially turn off the 'Category' axis type and set everything manually.  Sorry I can't see your picture at work to be more understanding of your situation so forgive me if I missed something.